# How to make a loop do the same thing again?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Basically, I want the if and else statements at the bottom to happen again when my counter reaches 13. How do I do it? My code is below.

```
int counter = 2;
int start = 19;
int end = 95;

while(!(input>=start && input<=end) /*range*/ && counter<100){

               start+=95;
               end+=95;

                   if(counter % 4 == 0)
                       end+=19;
                   else if(counter % 5 == 0)
                    start+=19;

               counter++;
        }
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry for being unclear. Uhh, what I want to do is, if the if-else statements have already been executed 13 times, I want the whole thing, including the

```
start+=95;
end+=95;
```

to execute again.

Comment: use goto and simple check if(counter==13) goto label

Comment: Your question is not really clear. what do you mean by happen again? They will run if your counter reaches 13, but your loop will run only once becayse you add 95 units to the start and end variables. in your while loop in the beginning.

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make any sense. If counter is 13, then neither of those branches will execute. `13 % 4 = 1` and `13 % 5 = 3`, performing them twice will just do nothing twice.

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/54-goto-statements/

Comment: @dato 1) This is Java not C++. 2) Goto is bad practice.

Comment: Actually, you can have labeled statements in Java and jump to them on a continue or break, just like a goto (you can check the the tutorial [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)). But i definitely agree with you, they are generally a bad practice.

Comment: You'll need to pay very close attention to the initial value of counter.

Answer (score 1):

wrap the codes in the loop into a method. when executes every 13 times, invoke the method again

Answer (score 0):

```
int innerLoop=(counter==13)?2:1;
for (int i=0; i<innerLoop; i++) {
... 
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this D:

Comment: Good.  There's a bug in my code anyhow because your counter starts at 2 :P.   This is clearly some sort of classroom assignment... so, what is it you're striving to learn?  Loops and conditionals?  My suggestion is to create a loop inside your while loop that executes twice only if your loop has executed exactly 13 times.